# how to redirect the user to his profile page after succesfully log in?

Tags: php, authentication

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$emailErr = $passwordErr = $log_in_wrong = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
  $emailErr = "Your email is required ";
}
if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
  $passwordErr = "Your password is required ";
}
$username_validate=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password, email FROM users WHERE password = '".$password."' AND  email = '".$email."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($username_validate)==0){
  $log_in_wrong = "The email or password are incorrect!";
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($username_validate)>=1){
  $log_in_correct = "si";
}
if($log_in_correct == 'si'){
$selectprofile = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectprofile);
$slug = $row['slug'];
header("Location: /profile.php?slug=$slug");
}}
 ?>
```

This is my code and i want to redirect the user to his profile page. the user profile page would be profile.php?slug=$slug.
the '$slug' is what i use to identify each page.
Maybe my query is wrong or i something like that. Thank You!

Comment: can you share what errors you get?

Comment: I dont really have errors. The thing is that when i log in correctly, it redirect me to the first slug of my database and i want it to redirect me to the user slug that is logging in. Thank you for reaching out!

Answer (score 0):

use post method and in action keep userprofile.php file (userprofile.php is example.) first try this simply and then append data on url.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the last query because it took any slug from database, but if you add select slug on the first query, is going to give you the user slug that logged in recently. Thank to all of you!